# Laravel Migration for Followers / Following

Tags: php, laravel, comments, acl, posts

I am setting up a migration for user followers. I want to use this to check if a user is following another user and if he is enabled to see and comment on the publisher posts.

I am doing this based on this example:

[image: example]

I wrote this:

```
class CreateFollowersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('followers', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->unsignedInteger('publisher_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
            $table->unsignedInteger('follower_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
            $table->boolean('enable_follow')->default('1')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('publisher_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('follower_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        schema::drop('followers');
    }
}
```

Use of this table should be as follow:

1) a User can (click) follow a Publisher and so become a follower as per the table. Example `Publisher_id = 1; Follower_id = 2; enable_follow = 1;` 
The user with id 2 is now following user id 1 and can see the posts of that user **on a feed** like for example in twitter. The user is enabled to see the posts and to comment on those posts as enable_follow is set to 1

2) A Publisher can ban a user from seeing or commenting on his posts, example `Publisher_id = 1; Follower_id = 2; enable_follow = 0;`

Question: which users can see (**after a search for posts, not on the feed**) and comment on other users posts?
Answer: every user unless the publisher, after getting an unwanted comment, decides to ban the user who posted the unwanted comment.

Before commenting there is no relationship at all in the followers table between the two users. The relationship is created after the publisher bans the user and will be like in example number 2 `Publisher_id = 1; Follower_id = 2; enable_follow = 0;`

So basically 'follower_id' is really acting both as follower and commenter.

Comment: Okay that makes sense.  You need the record in the `followers` table so that the publisher's posts can show up in the users feed.  The user can still search out any publisher/posts he is not currently "subscribed" to.

Answer (score 0):

I would say this schema should be able to handle the functionality you are looking for.

The only thing I don't understand is the nullable foreign keys.  I'm not sure it's necessary to have them nullable or what it would mean if one was null.  It also probably would not hurt having them nullable or if it would ever be possible.

Comment: How do you check if a user is not banned from posting comments or seeing the publisher posts if you drop the bool? The idea is that any user can comment or see another user post unless he is not banned. If the user follows the publisher then he will see the posts in his feed (e.g. Twitter).

Comment: Wait, I see what you are suggesting. By making an "ignores" table the follower_id associated to the publisher_id can't see or comment on posts, but the point is that I need the table for 2 purposes: 1) a user can follow a publisher and see the publisher's posts in a feed 2) a user can comment on the publisher posts regardless of his "following" status. So I need 'enable_follow' to let the publisher ban the follower.

Comment: I think you should clarify your question perhaps with what you want exactly.  What determines if a user can view another user's post and what determines if a user can comment on another user's post and also remove the things that contradict each other.

Comment: I don't see what is contradicting what. I will try to explain better though.

Comment: now I'm thinking something else. How do you add a contraint to the table to check the the publisher_id is not equal to the follower_id ? I mean, a user can't follow himself.

Comment: I don't believe that's possible, it would have to be handled in the code when you save.  However, that gave me another thought.  You might want to add a unique key to the `publisher_id` and `follower_id` columns so someone can't follow a publisher multiple times.

Comment: what happens if I put the unique key on those? Shouldn't this restrict the possibility to add more than a key pair for each publisher_id follower_id ? I mean if I set those to unique then I can only have one row. Probably the check should be done in code ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified.  When you add the unique index, make sure to include both columns in the same index.  That would make it impossible for a user to subscribe to the same publisher multiple times but would still allow a user to subscribe to multiple different publishers.

Comment: how do you do it with the schema builder ?